# How to access hidden superclass instance variables from a subclass body?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am stuck at the given code as it says to access all the values of **a** in the given multilevel inheritance without creating the object of the class .

```
class A{
    public int a = 100;
}

class B extends A{
    public int a = 80;
}

class C extends B{
    public int a = 60;
}

class D extends C{
    public int a = 40;
}

class E extends D{
    public int a =10;
    public void show(){
        int a = 0;
        **// How to access all values of (a) here without creating object.**
    }
}

public class Inheritance5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new E().show();
        A a1 = new E();
        D d1 = (D) a1;
    }
}
```

---

AFAIK, instance variables can be only accessed once an object is created for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AFAIK, instance variables can be only accessed once an object is
>   created for them.

`show()` is an instance method. So, it is already  operates on an instance.
Besides, as a constructor is invoked, its parent constructor is invoked.
So the constructors of all the hierarchy classes of `E` that declare their own `a` variable were invoked.

To refer the `a` declared in the `D` parent class, you can do `super.a`.
Now for the remaining, it is a little tricky but you could cast `this` to each parent class to be able to refer their `a` variable :

```
public void show() {
  int a = 0;
  int parentD = super.a;
  int parentC = ((C)this).a;
  int parentB = ((B)this).a;
  int parentA = ((A)this).a;
}
```

Note that you can do that because the `a` variable declared in the parent classes uses an access modifier that allows `D` instances to access to.
For example, it would not be possible if you used a `private` modifier.

Comment: (+1) It might be worth directly addressing the "instance variables can be only accessed once an object is created for them", by saying that, since `show()` is an instance method, it already is operating on an instance. I think this would segue nicely into casting `this`.

Comment: It is worthy indeed. Thank you for the remark.